# Store some special character in Backendless

Tags: ios, swift, backendless

How to do single column to validate all special characters, some character range and single space? And with what data type?

Answer (score 1):

The data type should definitely be a STRING, then you can validate it using a regular expression. Here is a tutorial on this topic: https://backendless.com/feature-54-validating-data-object-properties-with-regular-expressions/